# Use a variable for table/identifier name in stored procedure with Snowflake Scripting

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am creating a stored procedure using [Snowflake Scripting](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/variables.html) and I would like the output to be a table created with a date stamp. In SQL I would write this as

```
set creation_date = to_varchar(current_date(), 'YYYYMMDD');

set output_tbl_name = concat('my_database.my_schema.', 'output_', $creation_date);

create or replace table identifier($output_tbl_name) (col1 varchar, col2 varchar);
```

This would then create a table called output_20220216.

However if I use Snowflake Scripting in my stored procedure, the set function is not recognized. I tried using

```
let creation_date varchar := to_varchar(current_date(), 'YYYYMMDD');

let output_tbl_name varchar := concat('my_database.my_schema.', 'output_', $creation_date);

create or replace table identifier($output_tbl_name) (col1 varchar, col2 varchar);
```

But I get an error due to the $ symbol. If I use `create or replace table output_tbl_name`, it will just create a table called output_tbl_name.

How can I use identifiers in Snowflake Scripting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Snowflake Scripting and EXECUTE IMMEDIATE with concatenated query:

```
DECLARE
   creation_date   STRING := to_varchar(current_date(), 'YYYYMMDD');
   output_tbl_name STRING := concat('my_database.my_schema.', 'output_', :creation_date);
   QUERY           STRING;
BEGIN

   QUERY:= REPLACE(          
         'create or replace table <output_tbl_name>(col1 varchar, col2 varchar);'
         ,'<output_tbl_name>', :output_tbl_name);         ;    

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :QUERY;
   
   RETURN :QUERY;
END;
```

Output(Classic UI):

[image]

```
SELECT * FROM my_database.my_schema.output_20220217;
-- COL1 COL2
```

Comment: This works, thank you so much! I just took the $$ rows out for the new Snowflake interface. Would you happen to know how to do something similar for an exported .csv file name? E.g. in my procedure I want to export the output table name out and want to similarly dynamically name the csv with the date stamp.

Comment: One more question for you, if you happen to know:

In the same procedure, I am hoping to create the table as a select statement from another table.

Something like 

declare start_date date := add_months(current_date(), -6) --for 6 months prior

create or replace output_20220217 as select * from source_tbl where date > <start_date>;

How can I incorporate the second variable into the query?

Comment: Hi @SamreenHaque Glad to hear I could help :) Please consider asking new questions as extending the scope of initial question that was already answered is not the exact way how the SO works.

Comment: Thank you Lukasz, I'll post new questions for the above!